# Procedure is not executing. Error message is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in postgresql.

```
create procedure add_future_tickers_intl(
   v_ticker_serial numeric,
   v_source_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_ticker_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_sector_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_status character,
   v_market_md character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_source_ticker_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_instrument_type_id numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_currency_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_country_code character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_decimal_places numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_decimal_correction_factor numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_parent_ticker_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_parent_source_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_isin_code character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_lot_size numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric, v_unit character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_display_ticker character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_last_updated_on timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
   v_comments character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_listing_date timestamp without time zone,
   v_listing_status numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_stock_published_status character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_max_stocks numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_is_settlement_to numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_is_main_stock numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_last_updated_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
   v_currency_correction_factor numeric,
   v_global_sector_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_dfn_sector character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_category character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_index_type numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_source_source_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_wkn character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_reuter_ssymbol character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_bloomberg_symbol character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_symbol_status character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_eligibility_id numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_sharia_compliant numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_symbolcode character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_exchange_status numeric,
   v_assct_ticker_serial numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_ticker_assctn_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
   v_first_trading timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
   v_idx_main_source_id character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_otc numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_clearance_duration character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_lasttradabledate timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
   v_all_descriptions character varying,
   v_maturity_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
   v_cusip character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_is_desc_updated numeric DEFAULT 1,
   v_bbgid character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_bbgid_composite character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_dec_lot_size numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_ticker_classification numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_display_decimal_places numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_ticksize numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_sharesoutstanding numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_ticker_class_l1 numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_ticker_class_l2 numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_ticker_class_l3 numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_tick_size_string character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_mic_code character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_min_size numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_max_long_size numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_max_short_size numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_margin_percentage numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_display_symbol character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_sedol character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
   v_stamp_duty_flag numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_margin_initial_cash numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
   v_margin_maintenance_cash numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric
)
    language edbspl
as
$$
        v_is_manually_modified                number(1);
    begin

    begin -- insert block
        add_ticker_intl (
            v_ticker_serial,
            v_source_id,
            v_ticker_id,
            v_sector_id,
            v_status,
            v_market_md,
            v_source_ticker_id,
            v_instrument_type_id,
            v_currency_id,
            v_country_code,
            v_decimal_places,
            v_decimal_correction_factor,
            v_parent_ticker_id,
            v_parent_source_id,
            v_isin_code,
            v_lot_size,
            v_unit,
            v_display_ticker,
            v_last_updated_on,
            v_comments,
            v_listing_date,
            v_listing_status,
            v_stock_published_status,
            v_max_stocks,
            v_is_settlement_to,
            v_is_main_stock,
            v_last_updated_time,
            v_currency_correction_factor,
            v_global_sector_id,
            v_dfn_sector,
            v_category,
            v_index_type,
            v_source_source_id,
            v_wkn,
            v_reuter_ssymbol,
            v_bloomberg_symbol,
            v_symbol_status,
            v_eligibility_id,
            v_sharia_compliant,
            v_symbolcode,
            v_exchange_status,
            v_assct_ticker_serial,
            v_ticker_assctn_date,
            v_first_trading,
            v_idx_main_source_id,
            v_otc,
            v_clearance_duration,
            v_lasttradabledate,
            v_all_descriptions,
            v_cusip,
            v_is_desc_updated,
            v_bbgid,
            v_bbgid_composite,
            v_dec_lot_size,
        v_ticker_classification,
            v_display_decimal_places,
            null,
            null,
            v_TickSize,
        v_SharesOutstanding,
            v_ticker_class_L1,
            v_ticker_class_L2,
            v_ticker_class_L3,
            v_tick_size_string,
            v_mic_code,
            v_min_size,
            v_max_long_size,
            v_max_short_size,
            v_margin_percentage,
            v_display_symbol,
            v_sedol,
            v_stamp_duty_flag
            
        );

        insert into future_tickers
        (
            ticker_serial,
            contract_size,
            maturity_date,
            exp_date,
            parent_source_id,
            parent_ticker_id,
            last_updated_on,
            DECIMAL_SUPPORTED_LOT_SIZE,
            MARGIN_INITIAL_CASH,
            MARGIN_MAINTENANCE_CASH
        )
        values
        (
            v_ticker_serial,
            v_lot_size,
            v_maturity_date,
            v_lasttradabledate,
            v_parent_source_id,
            v_parent_ticker_id,
            v_last_updated_on,
            v_dec_lot_size,
            v_margin_initial_cash,
            v_margin_maintenance_cash
        );

        exception
            when dup_val_on_index
            then

            begin -- insert into block
                select is_manually_modified
                into v_is_manually_modified
                from tickers
                where ticker_serial=v_ticker_serial;

            exception
            when no_data_found
              then v_is_manually_modified := null;

            end; -- insert into block

                if (v_is_manually_modified <> 1 or v_is_manually_modified is null)
                then
                    update future_tickers
                    set
                        contract_size = v_lot_size,
                        maturity_date = v_maturity_date,
                        exp_date = v_lasttradabledate,
                        parent_source_id = v_parent_source_id,
                        parent_ticker_id = v_parent_ticker_id,
                        last_updated_on = v_last_updated_on,
                        DECIMAL_SUPPORTED_LOT_SIZE = v_dec_lot_size,
                        MARGIN_INITIAL_CASH = v_margin_initial_cash,
                        MARGIN_MAINTENANCE_CASH = v_margin_maintenance_cash
                    where
                        ticker_serial = v_ticker_serial;
                end if;

        end; -- insert block
        --commit;

    end add_future_tickers_intl
$$;

alter procedure add_future_tickers_intl(numeric, varchar, varchar, varchar, char, varchar, varchar, numeric, varchar, varchar, numeric, numeric, varchar, varchar, varchar, numeric, varchar, varchar, timestamp, varchar, timestamp, numeric, varchar, numeric, numeric, numeric, timestamp, numeric, varchar, varchar, varchar, numeric, varchar, varchar, varchar, varchar, varchar, numeric, numeric, varchar, numeric, numeric, timestamp, timestamp, varchar, numeric, varchar, timestamp, varchar, timestamp, varchar, numeric, varchar, varchar, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, varchar, varchar, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, varchar, varchar, numeric, numeric, numeric) owner to office;
```

When I try to execute the following call,

```
call pkg_ticker_utils.add_future_tickers_intl(
   12768341,
   'FCBT',
   'TY\M23',
   null,
   '1',
   null,
   'F:TY\M23',
   68,
   'USD',
   null,
   9,
   10000000,
   'TY\P',
   null,
   null,
   1000,
   'Metric Ton ',
   'TYM3',
   '2023-02-08 04:42:24.808+00',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   '2023-06-21 00:00:00+00',
   '0'::numeric,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   '674',
   null,
   null,
   'TYM3 CBT',
   null,
   null,
   null,
   'TYM3',
   0,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   '2023-06-21 00:00:00+00',
   'EN^XTen-Year US Treasury Note Futures Jun-2023 Composite^XTen-Year US Treasury Note Futures Jun-2023 Composite^X|',
   null,
   null,
   1,
   'BBG019PMT181',
   null,
   '0'::numeric,
   null,
   3,
   '0'::numeric,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   null,
   '0'::numeric,
   null,
   null,
   '0'::numeric,
   'TYM3',
   null,
   0,
   null,
   null
);
```

it is throwing error:

> [42883] ERROR: procedure pkg_ticker_utils.add_future_tickers_intl(integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown) does not exist Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 6

At the end it says:
**Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 6**

I do not understand what it means in the end, by ***position 6*** ?

I have tried to count the parameters and all, and they all match. I do not see any discrepancies.

I have tried to count the parameters, match the types and all and it all checks out. What do I have wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what edbspl is. If you are using a PostgreSQL fork you should tag your question with that fork.

Comment: 1) You do `call pkg_ticker_utils.add_future_tickers_intl`, does `add_future_tickers_intl` exist in the schema `pkg_ticker_utils` 2) Do you have more then one version of the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Good luck with finding someone who is ready to dig through tons of parameters.

My advice: avoid `character varying` or any other non-preferred type in function arguments. Use preferred types, because they facilitate type resolution:

```
SELECT typname, typcategory FROM pg_type WHERE typispreferred;

   typname   │ typcategory 
═════════════╪═════════════
 bool        │ B
 text        │ S
 oid         │ N
 float8      │ N
 inet        │ I
 timestamptz │ D
 interval    │ T
 varbit      │ V
(8 rows)
```

The exception is probably with the numeric types, as you don't want to use `double precision` there. There, it is best to use types that can be cast to implicitly, so prefer the right-hand types over the left-hand types in the following list:

```
SELECT c.castsource::regtype, c.casttarget::regtype
FROM pg_cast AS c
   JOIN pg_type AS t1 ON c.castsource = t1.oid
   JOIN pg_type AS t2 ON c.casttarget = t2.oid
WHERE t1.typcategory = 'N'
  AND t2.typcategory = 'N'
  AND c.castcontext = 'i'
  AND t2.typname !~~ ALL ('{oid,reg%}');

 castsource │    casttarget    
════════════╪══════════════════
 bigint     │ real
 bigint     │ double precision
 bigint     │ numeric
 smallint   │ bigint
 smallint   │ integer
 smallint   │ real
 smallint   │ double precision
 smallint   │ numeric
 integer    │ bigint
 integer    │ real
 integer    │ double precision
 integer    │ numeric
 real       │ double precision
 numeric    │ real
 numeric    │ double precision
 numeric    │ numeric
(16 rows)
```

Since your main question seems to be the "position 6": that is the position in the SQL statement that is related to the error, so probably the procedure call:

```
CALL procname(tons_of_parameters);
     ^
     |
   here
```

Comment: My main issue is that what do they mean by position 6. Is it 6th character, 6th word? What do they mean by this error message?

Comment: Ah, I see. I have added that to the answer.